# mongoose - field contained in string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to make the following query, I have a model in the db that holds a string. for example lets say that's the data:

```
[{ a : 'test/t' },
{ a : 'test/b' }]
```

Now I have the following string

```
var search = 'http://ttt.com/test/t'
```

I want to make a query which will find all the documents that 'a' property is contained inside the search variable, case insensetive.
All the exmaples I've seen talk about the opposite equation.

Comment: Do you care a lot about query execution times?

Comment: Of course I would like it to be as fast as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query for the operation which uses the short for [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/). Since this runs in Javascript, expect it to run slowly.

```
db.coll.find(function () {
    var re = new RegExp(this.a.replace("/", "\/"))
    return 'http://ttt.com/test/t'.match(re)
});
```

Comment: isn't there a better solution? it's wired the mongo guys haven't thought this through

Comment: i get  'Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined' , the 'this' object is referred to a promise

Comment: Do you have a field `a` in the data? You can use `this` or `obj` here